# Avoid database corrupted if android kills while creating

Tags: android, sqlite, lifecycle

and thanks in advance!

I'm wondering what happends if android kills your app, If in this moment you are creating the database structure.
In my case, database creation takes a while, because there are many elements to insert (about 20/25 seconds). If user thinks "I'm gonna check my mail while it ends" and puts my app in background, android will be able to kill the app (as says documentation)
¿How can avoid it? In this moment, datacase creates from an AsyncTask to not block user interface... ¿What do you think about this (possible) problem?

Thanks again, and regards!!

Answer (score 2):

Use SQLite Transaction! It will not only speed up the database operations but will also avoid the danger of database corruption.

Comment: Hi, and sorry for my late response. In seems a good solution, but a commit of 3000 or more inserts will not be problematic?

Comment: in fact it always recommended to use transactions for large number of inserts. it speeds up the processing. This is what SQLite's official site says: `By default, each INSERT statement is its own transaction. But if you surround multiple INSERT statements with BEGIN...COMMIT then all the inserts are grouped into a single transaction. The time needed to commit the transaction is amortized over all the enclosed insert statements and so the time per insert statement is greatly reduced`

Comment: Ok! Thank you for your quick response, I was wrong in that way! Is good to learn something every day, hehe